# Tiffeneau–Demjanov rearrangement products

Tags: organic-chemistry, rearrangements

With reference to the paper McCasland, G. E. Pinacolic Rearrangements of Epimeric Aminocyclanols. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1951,** *73* (5), 2293–2295 [DOI: 10.1021/ja01149a110](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01149a110). ([ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231487495_Pinacolic_Rearrangements_of_Epimeric_Aminocyclanols1) link). It states that

> **cis-2-Aminocyclohexanol** on treatment with nitrous acid undergoes a pinacol rearrangement, yielding both **cyclohexanone** and **cyclopentylmethanal** as products.

However, it goes on to state that the **trans** epimer would specifically yield the latter as the major product. Can someone explain this (preferably via mechanism)?

Comment: I would suggest that you draw out three-dimensional structures for both starting materials.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quite a fun one to work out. The first thing to know is that there is a stereoelectronic requirement for the migrating group to be *anti* to the leaving group ($\ce{N2+}$), for orbital overlap reasons.

[image: mechanism]

(apologies for hand-drawing - doing this on my phone)

You need to consider the chair conformations of both stereoisomers, in both possible ring-flip forms. For the *cis* stereoisomer, you would expect roughly a 1:1 mixture of ring-flip forms. When the $\ce{OH}$ is axial, the group *anti* to the LG is H, and the cyclohexanone is formed. Similarly, when $\ce{OH}$ is equatorial, the $\ce{C-C}$ bond is *anti* and the cyclopentane product is formed.

Now, for the *trans*-isomer there are two factors favouring the cyclopentane. First, the chair form in which both groups are equatorial will predominate, and this is the stereoisomer that leads to the cyclopentane. Secondly, in the (minor) conformer where the $\ce{OH}$ and $\ce{N2}$ are axial, there is no *anti* group to migrate according to the normal mechanism. The OH itself is *anti* to the $\ce{N2}$, and I'm not aware (off the top of my head) of any examples of 1,2-hydroxy shifts. However, I expect some epoxide might be formed *via* an S<sub>N</sub>2 pathway.

Answer (score 10):

I took the opportunity to read the McCasland paper<sup>1</sup> to which the OP's link referred. The products were isolated as their 2,4-dinitrophenylhydrazones. In the case of the *cis*-isomer **4**, the reaction mixture was "apparently richer" in the aldehyde **3**.
As @PCK has argued for the *trans*-isomer **1** the highlighted bonds are aligned properly for a ring contraction. Clearly, the diaxial conformation of **1** is not a factor.
Assuming that the diazonium group has an A-value similar to that of cyanide (0.2 kcal/mol; OH, 1.0 kcal/mol), the equilibrium constant for the two *cis* conformations at ambient temperature is 3.8, which favors conformation **4b**. If indeed the formation of aldehyde **3** predominates over cyclohexanone **5**, then hydride migration must be a slower process than ring contraction. In the event, orbital overlap of the red bonds in **4** is essential.

[image]

1) [G. E. McCasland, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1951**, *73*, 2293](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01149a110)